# Add to a header of Authorization c# API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, authorization

how to add to a header of Authorization?

I am trying to write :

```
requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic Og==");
```

But it brings me such an error:

> The format of value 'Basic Og==' is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it by following way

```
requestMessage.Headers.Authorization= new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
var requestMessage= new HttpClient();
requestMessage.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "key=XXX");
```